# .autocomplete() not working in second ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have created am using autocomplete on my site following my code for autocomplete it is working fine for first time Ajax response comes but it is not working second time.

Please help

Auto complete Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#txtarriving").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
    selectFirst: true
  });
});
```

Ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "flight_module.php?btntype=flight", 
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(html) {
       $(".Mydiv").hide();
        $('#outputdiv').html(html).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess you have to reinitialize autocomplete plugin on new added element. Of course, IDs must be unique on document context, just saying